# Entity Framework generates datetime2 parameters for comparing to a date column -- how to match the data type of the column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there anyway to force Entity Framework into sending `date` parameters to match the column data type? This is causing a very costly key lookup in some of our queries.

An example generated query runs in minutes, I grabbed from SQL Server profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [table] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [search] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[Number] = [Extent2].[Number]) AND ([Extent2].[SearchInstance] = @p__linq__0)
        )) AND ([Extent1].[Date] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= @p__linq__2)
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='1A530478-17F8-442E-B718-32049086717F',@p__linq__1='2012-07-24',@p__linq__2='2015-07-24'
```

If I manually change the types of the parameters to date, this query executes in 0 seconds.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [table] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [search] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[Number] = [Extent2].[Number]) AND ([Extent2].[SearchInstance] = @p__linq__0)
        )) AND ([Extent1].[Date] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= @p__linq__2)
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1 date,@p__linq__2 date',@p__linq__0='1A530478-17F8-442E-B718-32049086717F',@p__linq__1='2012-07-24',@p__linq__2='2015-07-24'
```

Using ef codefirst, I specifed `.HasColumType("date")` but did not change the parameter type being sent.

** names of tables & columns have been changed to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 1):

Crudely, using a DbInterceptor.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

public static class SomewhereDoThis 
{
    public static void Register() 
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new DateInterceptor());
    }
}

public class DateInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    /* .. */

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        ShrinkDates(command);
    }
    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        ShrinkDates(command);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        ShrinkDates(command);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        ShrinkDates(command);
    }

    private static void ShrinkDates(DbCommand command)
    {
        command.Parameters
            .OfType<SqlParameter>()
            .Where(p => p.SqlDbType == SqlDbType.DateTime2)
            .Where(p => p.Value != DBNull.Value)
            .Where(p => p.Value is DateTime)
            .Where(p => ((DateTime)p.Value).TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(p => p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date);
    }
}
```